Graph API New-MgUserMessage always draft
When using the New-MgUserMessage, it creates the file in the Drafts folder. If I use Move-MgUserMessage to the Inbox, and then try the Update-MgUserMessage isdraft to False, it is still marked as a draft. It also isn't allowing me to set the -ReceivedDateTime -SentDateTime or the -IsDraft properties. This is what I have right now. I have removed the specified properties and tried to replace them with the PID equivalent, but this just fails to even create a new message.
foreach ($message in $messages) {
    $messageCount++
    
    # Prepare recipients
    $toRecipients = if ($message.ToRecipients) {
        try {
            ($message.ToRecipients | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = $_.EmailAddress.Address
                        Name = $_.EmailAddress.Name
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Unable to parse ToRecipients. Using original value."
            $message.ToRecipients
        }
    }

    $ccRecipients = if ($message.CcRecipients) {
        try {
            ($message.CcRecipients | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = $_.EmailAddress.Address
                        Name = $_.EmailAddress.Name
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Unable to parse CcRecipients. Using original value."
            $message.CcRecipients
        }
    }

    $bccRecipients = if ($message.BccRecipients) {
        try {
            ($message.BccRecipients | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = $_.EmailAddress.Address
                        Name = $_.EmailAddress.Name
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Unable to parse BccRecipients. Using original value."
            $message.BccRecipients
        }
    }

    # Create new message
    $newMessage = @{
        Subject = $message.Subject
        Body = @{
            ContentType = "HTML"
            Content = $message.BodyHtml
        }
        BodyPreview = $message.BodyPreview
        Importance = $message.Importance
        Categories = $message.Categories -split ','
        IsReadReceiptRequested = [bool]$message.IsReadReceiptRequested
        IsDeliveryReceiptRequested = [bool]$message.IsDeliveryReceiptRequested
        IsRead = [bool]$message.IsRead
        InternetMessageId = $message.InternetMessageId
        ConversationId = $message.ConversationId
        ConversationIndex = $message.ConversationIndex
        InferenceClassification = $message.InferenceClassification
        HasAttachments = [bool]$message.HasAttachments
        WebLink = $message.WebLink
        From = @{
            EmailAddress = @{
                Name = $message.FromName
                Address = $message.FromEmail
            }
        }
        SingleValueExtendedProperties = @(
            @{
                Id = "Integer 0x0E07"
                Value = "4"
            }
            @{
                Id = "SystemTime 0x0039"
                Value = $message.SentDateTime
            }
            @{
                Id = "SystemTime 0x0E06"
                Value = $message.ReceivedDateTime
            }
        )
    }

    # Add recipients only if they exist
    if ($toRecipients) { $newMessage.ToRecipients = $toRecipients }
    if ($ccRecipients) { $newMessage.CcRecipients = $ccRecipients }
    if ($bccRecipients) { $newMessage.BccRecipients = $bccRecipients }

    # Add ReplyTo if it exists
    if ($message.ReplyTo) {
        try {
            $replyTo = $message.ReplyTo | ConvertFrom-Json
            $newMessage.ReplyTo = $replyTo
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Unable to parse ReplyTo. Using original value."
            $newMessage.ReplyTo = $message.ReplyTo
        }
    }

    # Add Flag if it exists
    if ($message.Flag) {
        try {
            $flag = $message.Flag | ConvertFrom-Json
            $newMessage.Flag = $flag
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Unable to parse Flag. Using original value."
            $newMessage.Flag = $message.Flag
        }
    }

    # Create the message in the destination mailbox
    $createdMessage = New-MgUserMessage -UserId $user.Id -BodyParameter $newMessage

    # Check if the message has attachments
    if ([bool]$message.HasAttachments) {
        # Fetch attachments for this message
        $attachments = Get-AttachmentsForMessage -messageInternetMessageId $message.InternetMessageId

        foreach ($attachment in $attachments) {
            $attachmentCount++
            #Write-Host "  Processing attachment $attachmentCount : $($attachment.Name)"

            $attachmentParams = @{
                "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"
                Name = $attachment.Name
                ContentType = $attachment.ContentType
                ContentBytes = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes)
            }

            # Add attachment to the created message
            New-MgUserMessageAttachment -UserId $user.Id -MessageId $createdMessage.Id -BodyParameter $attachmentParams | Out-Null
        }
    }

    # Move the message to the Inbox
    Move-MgUserMessage -UserId $user.Id -MessageId $createdMessage.Id -DestinationId 'Inbox' | Out-Null
}

I have tried it with the New-MgUserMessage, and the Update-MgUserMessage and neither sets these properties, even though they say they are available properties to use. I am currently trying to use the PID values directly, as shown in the answer here Create new mail message with Microsoft Graph API, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I just get an "ErrorInvalidValueForProperty" error. I've also tried moving the email first, but no matter what I do, it never sets these properties. I also tried removing the FLAGS when I create the new message, just in case it was messing with these items.

I would suggest you just use Invoke-MgGraphRequest rather the New-mgusermessage as it outside of what those cmdlets are really designed for as your more trying to import a message. Update-MgUserMessage won't work because the extendedproperties your trying to set can only be set when the Message is created Eg I would suggest something like this which works okay for me


$MailboxName = "user@domain.com"
$InboxId = (Get-MgUserMailFolder -UserId $MailboxName -MailFolderId Inbox).Id

$Message = @{
    subject = "Did you see last night's game?"
    importance = "Low"
    body = @{
        contentType = "HTML"
        content = "They were <b>awesome</b>!"
    }
    toRecipients = @(
        @{
            emailAddress = @{
                address = "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    )
    Sender = @{
        emailAddress = @{
            address = "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = @(
        @{
            Id = "Integer 0x0E07"
            Value = "4"
        }
        @{
            Id = "SystemTime 0x0039"
            Value = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
        }
        @{
            Id = "SystemTime 0x0E06"
            Value = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
        }
    )
}

Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method POST -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$mailboxName/Mailfolders/$InboxId/Messages -Body $Message




Thank you! I'll be testing this out tomorrow. I noticed this option online, but I didn't fully understand it when compared to everything else. I just started learning the graph API a couple weeks ago so I don't have it mastered yet. I assume this method works for you in creating messages while preserving the timestamps and draft settings?

I was too excited to test this, since I had already been working on it for 2-3 days already. It worked perfectly, thank you so much!
